# Nautilus can't see files on a NTFS partitions, but 'ls' command shows them?

Tags: nautilus, ntfs

This is a weird one. Nautilus suddenly stopped showing any files in the Desktop folder of my Windows 7 partition. It correctly shows files in all other folders. What's even stranger is that if I do

```
cd /windows/Users/myuser/Desktop
ls -l
```

from the terminal, all the files show, no problem.

### Update

Just noticed this part of the output of ls, I think this is the culprit:

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root plugdev 4096 2012-01-04 00:26 MyDirectory1
d????????? ? ?    ?          ?                ? MyDirectory2
```

I had copied 'MyDirectory2' from my Linux partition to Windows while running Ubuntu. I know linux NTFS support is not as good as the native Windows support, so may be something went wrong. I can't delete this file. Trying to delete it (with 'rm -r MyDirectory2') gives:

```
rm: cannot remove `MyDirectory2': Input/output error
```

Comment: Maybe they are hidden, because of a leading `.` in the filename or a `~` at the end of the filename? Press `CTRL`+`H` in Nautilus to display also hidden files.

Comment: Tried, but didn't help.

Comment: Did you start Windows meanwhile? Afaik Windows does a file system check during booting after Ubuntu used the partition. Maybe this can repair something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've had this problem it turned out to be a permissions issue. Assuming your username on your system is satuon, you can change ownership of the files to your user with `chown -R satuon /windows/Users/myuser/Desktop`

You may need to use sudo (`sudo chown -R satuon /windows/Users/myuser/Desktop`) -- as with any command I'd encourage you to read `man chown` to understand what it does before you run it, especially as root.